# Using GROUP BY with an XMLCast and XMLQuery gives ORA-22950

Tags: xml, oracle, xmltype

The following is an example of what I am trying to do:

```
WITH xdata AS
         (SELECT 1 AS a_id,
                 xmltype ('<a>
                    <b>
                        <b_id>1</b_id>
                        <val>2</val>
                    </b>
                    <b>
                        <b_id>1</b_id>
                        <val>3</val>
                    </b>
                 </a>') AS xcol
            FROM DUAL
          UNION ALL
          SELECT 2 AS a_id,
                 xmltype ('<a>
                    <b>
                        <b_id>3</b_id>
                        <val>5</val>
                    </b>
                    <b>
                        <b_id>4</b_id>
                        <val>4</val>
                    </b>
                 </a>') AS xcol
            FROM DUAL)
  SELECT a_id,
         XMLCAST (
             XMLQUERY ('sum($doc/a/b/val/text())'
                       PASSING xcol AS "doc" RETURNING CONTENT) AS INTEGER)
             b_val
    FROM xdata
GROUP BY a_id, xcol;
```

When I run the above query, I get the error:

```
ORA-22950: cannot ORDER objects without MAP or ORDER method
```

If I remove the `GROUP BY` clause the query works fine.

The real world code that I'm working on requires me to use the `GROUP BY` clause. I went to every link in [this Google search results page](https://www.google.com/search?q=ORA-22950&gws_rd=ssl) but couldn't find any helpful information in the XML context. Please help me understand why this error appears in XMLCast and XMLQuery also.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: First of all, tell us what are you trying to achieve by that query. What is your *expected output* of the query. Why the code *requires* you to use the group by clause?

Comment: @nop77svk: I made this example query to help everyone run it on their systems. If you execute this query without the `GROUP BY` clause, you'll get exactly the output I want- `a_id` with sum of `'a/b/val'` node in `xcol`. Now, I want to group the results by `a_id`, at the least, but it gives me the error mentioned above. Any help will be much appreciated.

Comment: OK, the **sum of `a/b/val`** is *your expected output*. That's exactly what we needed to know.

Comment: So, sorry for being an idiot, but ... Why do you need the aggregation, then, if you can sum up the values with XQuery?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to aggregate via a value, the value must be sortable/hashable by, meaning that any two values have to be comparable (in order to be sorted/hashed). `XMLType` is not sortable/hashable. An object/class in Oracle is hashable/sortable when it has one of the special functions `map` or `order` defined. See [the respective Oracle documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/database/121/ADOBJ/adobjbas.htm#ADOBJ7084).

You are aggregating via `xcol`, which is an `XMLType` value. So, a resolution of your issue would be to aggregate via something else.

---

Based on the chaotic info you are giving us, two solutions come to my mind ...

**Solution 1**

```
WITH xdata AS
     (SELECT 1 AS a_id,
             xmltype ('<a>
                <b>
                    <b_id>1</b_id>
                    <val>2</val>
                </b>
                <b>
                    <b_id>1</b_id>
                    <val>3</val>
                </b>
             </a>') AS xcol
        FROM DUAL
      UNION ALL
      SELECT 2 AS a_id,
             xmltype ('<a>
                <b>
                    <b_id>3</b_id>
                    <val>5</val>
                </b>
                <b>
                    <b_id>4</b_id>
                    <val>4</val>
                </b>
             </a>') AS xcol
        FROM DUAL)
SELECT a_id,
     sum(XMLCAST (
         XMLQUERY ('sum($doc/a/b/val)'
                   PASSING xcol AS "doc" RETURNING CONTENT) AS INTEGER))
         b_val
FROM xdata
group by a_id;
```

**Solution 2**

```
WITH xdata AS
     (SELECT 1 AS a_id,
             xmltype ('<a>
                <b>
                    <b_id>1</b_id>
                    <val>2</val>
                </b>
                <b>
                    <b_id>1</b_id>
                    <val>3</val>
                </b>
             </a>') AS xcol
        FROM DUAL
      UNION ALL
      SELECT 2 AS a_id,
             xmltype ('<a>
                <b>
                    <b_id>3</b_id>
                    <val>5</val>
                </b>
                <b>
                    <b_id>4</b_id>
                    <val>4</val>
                </b>
             </a>') AS xcol
        FROM DUAL)
select X.a_id, sum(Y.b_val) as b_val
from xdata X
    cross join xmltable(
        '/a/b'
        passing X.xcol
        columns
            b_val integer path 'val'
    ) Y
group by X.a_id;
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer but what could be that something else?

Comment: I don't know yet. I'm still trying to figure what you need, what you can do and what you can't do.

Comment: Solution 1 seems good for me. I don't understand how could I not think about that.

Comment: Use getStringVal() method to convert XML to string so that it can work with group by.

Comment: @AshishKumar, that's wrong. getStringVal() does not convert XML to string, it merely extracts the XML text node and returns it as a varchar2 value.

Comment: @nop77svk Group By works when I use getStringVal() method and returns data in XML format with element name, attribute, value etc.

Comment: @AshishKumar, correct, now you speak exactly. The problem was that previously you used wording "convert XML to string" which is ambiguous in its meaning.

Answer (score 1):

Possibly really late for proposing a solution but I recently faced the same challenge when I was using **extract** and **xmltype** in the same query in order to retrieve certain xml data and was able to overcome it like this :

### Solution

```
select result, count(*) from (
   select extract(xmltype(xml_payload),'xpath','namespacedefinition').getStringVal() as result from x_table
) group by result;
```

Of course the wrapping of the main query is not necessary.

Good Luck!